# Understanding equality of used for proof (power series)

Tags: calculus

I am wondering if I am understanding this correctly: In the blue box there is an equality sign, the only reason for how I could understand that the left side of the equality sign is equal to whats on the right side of the equality sign is if the terms in the red boxes cancel each other out. Is this correct? And if it is can you actually simplify this without having conditions for the absolute terms?

[image]

Comment: You are correct, the circled terms do in fact cancel. The absolute value bars are there because the goal is to have an absolutely convergent series.

Comment: There are errors in your latex, the equations in your comment wont compile for me.

Comment: The double lefts and rights were causing you trouble: $$\left(\left| x_0-c\right| <0\lor \left| x_0-c\right| >0\right)\land \left| s-c\right| =\left| x_0-c\right|  \left| \frac{s-c}{x_0-c}\right|$$

Comment: @Joel Thank you, my point was that here you have conditions(in your post), do these condition have to apply for the cancelation to hold?

Comment: Here $x_0 \neq c$, thus $|x_0 - c| > 0$. You must have this in order to divide by $|x_0 - c|$. What this is saying is that once you have determined $x_0 \neq c$ for which this series converges (it always converges for $x_0 = c$), then it also converges whenever $|x-c| < |x_0 - c|$. That means it converges for any terms that are closer to $c$ than $x_0$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in these intermediate steps to make it more clear:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}(x-c)^{n}|=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}||x-c|^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}||x_{0}-c|^{n}\frac{|x-c|^{n}}{|x_{0}-c|^{n}}$$ $$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}||(x_{0}-c)^{n}|\left( \frac{|x-c|}{|x_{0}-c|}\right)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}(x_{0}-c)^{n}|\left |\frac{x-c}{x_{0}-c}\right|^{n}$$